# How to set Freestyle line set setting using python?

Tags: python

I want to make a blender script, to export wireframes.

Honestly I dont have much knowledge on the python thing so I only copied some code from the window over the gui and filled it in a text document.

But on this Code i have troubles:

```
bpy.context.scene.select_edge_mark = True
```

this one is for activating the Edge Mark checkbox from the Freestyle Addon.

```
bpy.context.space_data.context = 'RENDER_LAYER'
```

and this one should only change from window render to window render layer, but if the edge mark thing would work i wont need these code.

So, what i am doing wrong, or better, what is causing this, because honestly i think i am doing a lot wrong :D

Comment: PS: Error from console:

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "\Text", line 9, in <module>
AttributeError: 'Scene' object has no attribute 'select_edge_mark'
Error: Python script fail, look in the console for now...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Blender 2.80**

In order to activate the selection of edge marks you first need to access the Freestyle settings. These settings can be found in the [view layer](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.ViewLayer.html#bpy.types.ViewLayer.freestyle_settings) in Blender 2.80. Assuming your view layer is called "View Layer" you can access the settings using the following code:

```
freestyle_settings = bpy.context.scene.view_layers["View Layer"].freestyle_settings
```

Alternatively, if you always want to use the active view layer, then you can use the following instead:

```
freestyle_settings = bpy.context.window.view_layer.freestyle_settings
```

Next the [line sets](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.FreestyleSettings.html#bpy.types.FreestyleSettings.linesets) need to be accessed because the edge mark setting is configurable per line set. Assuming your line set is named "LineSet", you can access it the following way:

```
lineset = freestyle_settings.linesets["LineSet"]
```

Alternatively, if you always want to access the active line set, you can use the following instead:

```
lineset = freestyle_settings.linesets.active
```

Then you can enable the [edge mark selection](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.FreestyleLineSet.html#bpy.types.FreestyleLineSet.select_edge_mark) for the line set.

```
lineset.select_edge_mark = True
```

---

If you don't need access to the freestyle settings or the line set in other parts of your code you can also do this in a one-liner:

```
bpy.context.scene.view_layers["View Layer"].freestyle_settings.linesets["LineSet"].select_edge_mark = True
```

The alternative version when relying on the active view layer and line set looks like this:

```
bpy.context.window.view_layer.freestyle_settings.linesets.active.select_edge_mark = True
```

---

**Blender 2.79**

In order to activate the selection of edge marks you first need to access the Freestyle settings. These settings can be found in the [render layer](https://docs.blender.org/api/2.79/bpy.types.SceneRenderLayer.html?highlight=layers#bpy.types.SceneRenderLayer.freestyle_settings) in Blender 2.79. Assuming your render layer is called "RenderLayer" you can access the settings using the following code:

```
freestyle_settings = bpy.context.scene.render.layers["RenderLayer"].freestyle_settings
```

Alternatively, if you always want to use the active render layer, then you can use the following instead:

```
freestyle_settings = bpy.context.scene.render.layers.active.freestyle_settings
```

The rest is exactly the same as in Blender 2.80.

Comment: hm, it seems i am to stupid.

I have tried to insert one code after the other, error.

I tried the combined one, error.

I tried the other combined one, error :o

Can i send you my code in any way? i dont know how to do.

It always says:Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "\Text", line 19, in <module>
AttributeError: 'Scene' object has no attribute 'view_layers'
Error: Python script fail, look in the console for now...

Comment: @LukiKrew Are you using Blender 2.79?

Comment: yes i am using 2.79

Comment: The API changed between versions and my code examples are for 2.80. Give me a minute and I'll add the version for 2.79.

Comment: Thank you so much rjg if we get trough this i will be so greatful! Also i tried to make an alternative link for saving the export svg files on dekstop, it looks like this: #Render and Export on Desktop

shutil.copy(txtName, os.path.join(os.environ["HOMEPATH"], "Desktop"))

bpy.context.scene.render.filepath = "~/HOMEPATH/test.svg"

bpy.ops.render.render()      Any idea how this could be working :)?

Comment: Better add a new question for that, with some more details about what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: I wonder if it is possible to use the lineset from the editor in a python script to generate curves (works for me) from that? So instead of building the Operators in my script use what is in the freestyle " line seteditor"?

Comment: @CarstenWartmann I'm not really sure if I understand what you're trying to accomplish. You can't covert FreeStyle lines to actual objects. Please post a new question, since this is mostly unrelated to the original question and answer.

Comment: That convert of strokes to new objects is the part which works :) Will do a new Q